# Bool to int conversion with MSIL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cil

So of course I have seen many answers saying you can not cast bool to int explicitly or implicitly in c#. But I came up with an IL code to convert bool to int and it is as follows:

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.assembly 'bool2int'
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver  0:0:0:0
}

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit BoolToInt
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig static int32  Convert(bool args) cil managed
    {
      .maxstack  8
      IL_0000:  ldarg.0
      IL_0001:  ret
    }
}
```

Then after compiling the code into dll, you should be able to use it as:

```
BoolToInt.Convert(someBoolValue);
```

I came up with this using pieces of knowledge from other forums and MSIL tutorials. What I want want to know is:

How useful is this? How well does it perform? Is it the same as (or close to) the bool -> int implicit conversion in c/c++? Is it actually faster, or does it use Convert.ToInt32 under the hood? Is it even worth the effort?
I tried to gauge the performance but it didn't work. Even "if" statement doesn't seem to affect the performance in my profiler code, you get the point, I couldn't check the performance. I want to know what you think.

Note:
1)I did research the internet, I was into the topic o converting bool to int for a long time, never saw anyone mention writing an IL code for that.
2)Why I even think it would be faster in the first place is that on another thread concerning the performance issue of enums as dictionary key types, and one generic solution was to compile and use a similar IL code for struct (enum) to int converter and using that we could write a generic comparer for enum key type dictionaries. So I thought may be a similar code might help decrease branching a bit and gain me some performance boost :)

Comment: "you get the point, I couldn't check the performance" - no, I don't follow why you're unable to profile your code. You haven't shown *how* you've tried to profile it, which makes it hard to help you. But in general, if you're aiming for an optimization but can't find any way of seeing the difference between the simplest possible code and something that involves custom IL, I'd go with the simpler code...

Comment: Looks identical to `Unsafe.As<bool, int>(ref args)`. I think this is pretty pointless: the overhead of even calling your method is probably going to dominate, over the cost of doing something like `bool b = args ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: You can't implicitly, explicit is different. The compiler uses this rule to enforce program correctness, you're throwing this out the door. TBH it's kind of pointless in what you're trying to achieve; you're not going to see any difference if any.

Comment: The JIT compiler is probably clever enough not to actually branch in this instance. The other way, int to bool, is more useful as you can be silly and screw everyone up. C# compiler in a lot of places assumes `true` is always 1, it throws it off when you use 2 or something else. @canton7 aggressive inlining will presumably sort out the function call

Comment: It still branched in the snippets I tried on SharpLab, interestingly. I imagine branch prediction probably does a good job though